# Get OS information inside GitHub Action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I have a Javascript based GitHub action. 
How can I get to know the OS for which the action is currently running?
I want to execute few commands which require sudo privilege. So I need to make sure I do this only for linux based OS.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Javascript action, that means it's [running on Node.js](https://help.github.com/en/actions/building-actions/creating-a-javascript-action) so you can use the `OS` module.  Specifically, [`os.platform()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform) will return a value that you can use to determine if you need `sudo` or not:

> Returns a string identifying the operating system platform. The value is set at compile time. Possible values are `aix`, `darwin`, `freebsd`, `linux`, `openbsd`, `sunos`, and `win32`.